# Firefox displaying negative margin incorrectly

Tags: css, firefox, margin

My layout is working correctly, but not in Firefox. I am using a negative margin to indent the top and the bottom of the green box behind the YouTube video.

Here is how it should look:
[image: chrome screencap]

Here's how it looks in Firefox:
[image: firefox screencap]

Here's a live version to look at: [live site](http://danapaigetrentlage.com/cfsa-comps/lff-profilepage.html)

Here's a js fiddle of the relevant code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQMbu/)

I originally forgot to mention that the height is variable, because there will be different types of videos and photos within the .frame class. Is there any way to solve this Firefox problem without defining the height?

I'm also open to re-organizing this if there's a better way to write it and get the same effect.

Comment: IE9 standards mode gets it "wrong" too, IE9 'IE8 standards'  mode and compatibility view get it "right" ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take:

Watch more videos on our YouTube Channel

out of the  and put it just below

That fixes it for me, you'll then just need to shift the h4 to the left a bit which should be easy enough.

Hope that helps, below is the copied code

Martyn

Edit:
Leave the HTML alone, and change the css for: h4.caption to

```
h4.caption{
display:table;
padding-right:5px;
text-align:right;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but the width of the video is also variable. So I am using the captionwrap to right-align the "watch youtube channel" text to the right edge of the video.

Comment: edited so it affects just the css. This also seems to work, it's stopping the framewrap-gr div expanding over the h4

Comment: oh also, I noticed on firefox the menus, about our goods, find our... are slighly low in the boxes. take the padding out of .ffnav a and add in: line-height:30px; or how ever many px you want, the box will resize and middle align the text for you

Comment: This works!!! Thank you thank you thank you! So glad I don't have to rework everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the height of the green box it seems to sit fine.

```
.framewrap-gr { height: 390px; }
```

I only say this because your iframe height seems fixed.

---

After comment

I would recommend changing how you built it. Keep a container div, put a bg div and video div inside of it, z-index the video on top of the bg layer and style the bg layer how you need it (relative to their parent)

Comment: Ah! I forgot to mention, that there will be different videos and photos in the .frame so the height needs to be variable. Sorry.

Comment: Hmm... I am trying to layer the background color and video using z-index. I am having trouble getting the height of the background to be limited by the height of the video. Maybe I should write a new question.

Answer (score 0):

here is your css:

```
.framewrap-gr, .framewrap-fb, .framewrap-map {
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 50px 0 80px 0;
position: relative;
```

}

Try do it:

```
.framewrap-gr, .framewrap-fb, .framewrap-map {
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 50px 0 80px 0;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: -15px;
```

}

It can work, but if it doesnt, check what firebug says to you!

Sorry for the bad english, I'm Brazilian.